# How to upload two image form field in custom module?

Tags: magento-1.9, image, forms

How to upload two image form field in custom module?

in form field i have two image upload 
1. featured image
2. icon image.

i m confused that in module controller file how to code two image uploader?

here is my code..

**app\code\community\Mt\Service\controllers\Adminhtml\ServiceController.php**

```
<?php

class Mt_Service_Adminhtml_ServiceController extends Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action {

    protected function _initAction() {
        $this->loadLayout()->_setActiveMenu("service/service")->_addBreadcrumb(Mage::helper("adminhtml")->__("Service  Manager"), Mage::helper("adminhtml")->__("Service Manager"));
        return $this;
    }

    public function indexAction() {
        $this->_title($this->__("Service"));
        $this->_title($this->__("Manager Service"));

        $this->_initAction();
        $this->renderLayout();
    }

    public function editAction() {
        $this->_title($this->__("Service"));
        $this->_title($this->__("Service"));
        $this->_title($this->__("Edit Item"));

        $id = $this->getRequest()->getParam("id");
        $model = Mage::getModel("service/service")->load($id);
        if ($model->getId()) {
            Mage::register("service_data", $model);
            $this->loadLayout();
            $this->_setActiveMenu("service/service");
            $this->_addBreadcrumb(Mage::helper("adminhtml")->__("Service Manager"), Mage::helper("adminhtml")->__("Service Manager"));
            $this->_addBreadcrumb(Mage::helper("adminhtml")->__("Service Description"), Mage::helper("adminhtml")->__("Service Description"));
            $this->getLayout()->getBlock("head")->setCanLoadExtJs(true);
            $this->_addContent($this->getLayout()->createBlock("service/adminhtml_service_edit"))->_addLeft($this->getLayout()->createBlock("service/adminhtml_service_edit_tabs"));
            $this->renderLayout();
        } else {
            Mage::getSingleton("adminhtml/session")->addError(Mage::helper("service")->__("Item does not exist."));
            $this->_redirect("*/*/");
        }
    }

    public function newAction() {

        $this->_title($this->__("Service"));
        $this->_title($this->__("Service"));
        $this->_title($this->__("New Item"));

        $id = $this->getRequest()->getParam("id");
        $model = Mage::getModel("service/service")->load($id);

        $data = Mage::getSingleton("adminhtml/session")->getFormData(true);
        if (!empty($data)) {
            $model->setData($data);
        }

        Mage::register("service_data", $model);

        $this->loadLayout();
        $this->_setActiveMenu("service/service");

        $this->getLayout()->getBlock("head")->setCanLoadExtJs(true);

        $this->_addBreadcrumb(Mage::helper("adminhtml")->__("Service Manager"), Mage::helper("adminhtml")->__("Service Manager"));
        $this->_addBreadcrumb(Mage::helper("adminhtml")->__("Service Description"), Mage::helper("adminhtml")->__("Service Description"));


        $this->_addContent($this->getLayout()->createBlock("service/adminhtml_service_edit"))->_addLeft($this->getLayout()->createBlock("service/adminhtml_service_edit_tabs"));

        $this->renderLayout();
    }

    public function saveAction() {

        $post_data = $this->getRequest()->getPost();
        if ($post_data) {
            try {
                //Featured save image
                try {
                    if ((bool) $post_data['image']['delete'] == 1) {
                        $post_data['image'] = '';
                    } else {
                        unset($post_data['image']);
                        if (isset($_FILES)) {
                            if ($_FILES['image']['name']) {
                                if ($this->getRequest()->getParam("id")) {
                                    $model = Mage::getModel("service/service")->load($this->getRequest()->getParam("id"));
                                    if ($model->getData('image')) {
                                        $io = new Varien_Io_File();
                                        $io->rm(Mage::getBaseDir('media') . DS . implode(DS, explode('/', $model->getData('image'))));
                                    }
                                }
                                $path = Mage::getBaseDir('media') . DS . 'service' . DS . 'service' . DS;
                                $uploader = new Varien_File_Uploader('image');
                                $uploader->setAllowedExtensions(array('jpg', 'png', 'gif'));
                                $uploader->setAllowRenameFiles(true);
                                $uploader->setFilesDispersion(false);
                                $destFile = $path . $_FILES['image']['name'];
                                $filename = $uploader->getNewFileName($destFile);
                                $uploader->save($path, $filename);

                                $post_data['image'] = 'service/service/' . $filename;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                } catch (Exception $e) {
                    Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addError($e->getMessage());
                    $this->_redirect('*/*/edit', array('id' => $this->getRequest()->getParam('id')));
                    return;
                }
            //save image

                $model = Mage::getModel("service/service")
                        ->addData($post_data)
                        ->setId($this->getRequest()->getParam("id"))
                        ->save();

                Mage::getSingleton("adminhtml/session")->addSuccess(Mage::helper("adminhtml")->__("Service was successfully saved"));
                Mage::getSingleton("adminhtml/session")->setServiceData(false);

                if ($this->getRequest()->getParam("back")) {
                    $this->_redirect("*/*/edit", array("id" => $model->getId()));
                    return;
                }
                $this->_redirect("*/*/");
                return;
            } catch (Exception $e) {
                Mage::getSingleton("adminhtml/session")->addError($e->getMessage());
                Mage::getSingleton("adminhtml/session")->setServiceData($this->getRequest()->getPost());
                $this->_redirect("*/*/edit", array("id" => $this->getRequest()->getParam("id")));
                return;
            }
        }
        $this->_redirect("*/*/");
    }

    public function deleteAction() {
        if ($this->getRequest()->getParam("id") > 0) {
            try {
                $model = Mage::getModel("service/service");
                $model->setId($this->getRequest()->getParam("id"))->delete();
                Mage::getSingleton("adminhtml/session")->addSuccess(Mage::helper("adminhtml")->__("Item was successfully deleted"));
                $this->_redirect("*/*/");
            } catch (Exception $e) {
                Mage::getSingleton("adminhtml/session")->addError($e->getMessage());
                $this->_redirect("*/*/edit", array("id" => $this->getRequest()->getParam("id")));
            }
        }
        $this->_redirect("*/*/");
    }

    public function massRemoveAction() {
        try {
            $ids = $this->getRequest()->getPost('service_ids', array());
            foreach ($ids as $id) {
                $model = Mage::getModel("service/service");
                $model->setId($id)->delete();
            }
            Mage::getSingleton("adminhtml/session")->addSuccess(Mage::helper("adminhtml")->__("Item(s) was successfully removed"));
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            Mage::getSingleton("adminhtml/session")->addError($e->getMessage());
        }
        $this->_redirect('*/*/');
    }

    /**
     * Export order grid to CSV format
     */
    public function exportCsvAction() {
        $fileName = 'service.csv';
        $grid = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('service/adminhtml_service_grid');
        $this->_prepareDownloadResponse($fileName, $grid->getCsvFile());
    }

    /**
     *  Export order grid to Excel XML format
     */
    public function exportExcelAction() {
        $fileName = 'service.xml';
        $grid = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('service/adminhtml_service_grid');
        $this->_prepareDownloadResponse($fileName, $grid->getExcelFile($fileName));
    }

}
```

Here is Form.php
**app\code\community\Mt\Service\Block\Adminhtml\Service\Edit\Tab\Form.php**

```
<?php

class Mt_Service_Block_Adminhtml_Service_Edit_Tab_Form extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Form {

    protected function _prepareForm() {

        $form = new Varien_Data_Form();
        $this->setForm($form);
        $fieldset = $form->addFieldset("service_form", array("legend" => Mage::helper("service")->__("Item information")));


        $fieldset->addField("name", "text", array(
            "label" => Mage::helper("service")->__("Service Name"),
            "class" => "required-entry",
            "required" => true,
            "name" => "name",
        ));

        $fieldset->addField("description", "editor", array(
            "label" => Mage::helper("service")->__("Description"),
            "name" => "description",
            'style' => 'height:15em',
            'config' => Mage::getSingleton('cms/wysiwyg_config')->getConfig(),
            'wysiwyg' => true,
        ));

        $fieldset->addField('image', 'image', array(
            'label' => Mage::helper('service')->__('Featured Image'),
            'name' => 'image',
            'note' => '(*.jpg, *.png, *.gif)',
        ));

        $fieldset->addField('iconimage', 'image', array(
            'label' => Mage::helper('service')->__('Icon Image'),
            'name' => 'image',
            'note' => '(*.jpg, *.png, *.gif)',
        ));

        $fieldset->addField('backgroundcolor', 'text', array(
          'label'     => Mage::helper('service')->__('Background Color'),
          'name'      => 'backgroundcolor',
          'class'     => 'color {required:true, adjust:true, hash:true} validate-hex',
          'required'  => true,

        ));


        $fieldset->addField('status', 'select', array(
            'label' => Mage::helper('service')->__('Status'),
            'values' => Mt_Service_Block_Adminhtml_Service_Grid::getValueArray6(),
            'name' => 'status',
        ));
     /*    
        $fieldset->addField("instagramurl", "text", array(
            "label" => Mage::helper("service")->__("Instagram Url"),
            "name" => "instagramurl",
        ));
    */


        if (Mage::getSingleton("adminhtml/session")->getServiceData()) {
            $form->setValues(Mage::getSingleton("adminhtml/session")->getServiceData());
            Mage::getSingleton("adminhtml/session")->setServiceData(null);
        } elseif (Mage::registry("service_data")) {
            $form->setValues(Mage::registry("service_data")->getData());
        }
        return parent::_prepareForm();
    }

}
```

here is rendere image file.
**app\code\community\Mt\Service\Block\Adminhtml\Renderer\Image.php**

```
<?php

class Mt_Service_Block_Adminhtml_Renderer_Image extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid_Column_Renderer_Abstract {

    public function render(Varien_Object $row) {
        $mediaurl = '';
        $value = $row->getData($this->getColumn()->getIndex());
        if ($value) {
            $mediaurl = Mage::getBaseUrl(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_MEDIA) . DS . $value;
        } else {
            $mediaurl = $this->getSkinUrl() . '/service/service.png';
        }
        return '<p style="text-align:center;padding-top:5px;"><img src="' . $mediaurl . '"  style="width:80px;height:80px;text-align:center;"/></p>';
    }

}
```

**Like This..**

[image]

Comment: Both Image Name Should Store in Database Also

Comment: You need to put your image upload code for both of your image fields in **app\code\community\Mt\Service\controllers\Adminhtml\ServiceController.php::saveAction()**

Comment: ok, but how to write that code in same function?

Comment: Select inner `try catch` block, press `ctrl+c` and then press `ctrl+v`, change your file field name in new code, update store path and it will do.

Comment: i have do same thing but not work

Comment: Which update store path and it will do, ??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First update your **Form.php** file

```
$fieldset->addField('iconimage', 'image', array(
            'label' => Mage::helper('service')->__('Icon Image'),
            'name' => 'image',
            'note' => '(*.jpg, *.png, *.gif)',
        ));
```

to

```
$fieldset->addField('iconimage', 'image', array(
            'label' => Mage::helper('service')->__('Icon Image'),
            'name' => 'iconimage',
            'note' => '(*.jpg, *.png, *.gif)',
        ));
```

Now update your controller code **saveAction()**

```
public function saveAction() {
    $post_data = $this->getRequest()->getPost();
    if ($post_data) {
        try {
            //Featured save image
            try {
                if ((bool) $post_data['image']['delete'] == 1) {
                    $post_data['image'] = '';
                } else {
                    unset($post_data['image']);
                    if (isset($_FILES)) {
                        if ($_FILES['image']['name']) {
                            if ($this->getRequest()->getParam("id")) {
                                $model = Mage::getModel("service/service")->load($this->getRequest()->getParam("id"));
                                if ($model->getData('image')) {
                                    $io = new Varien_Io_File();
                                    $io->rm(Mage::getBaseDir('media') . DS . implode(DS, explode('/', $model->getData('image'))));
                                }
                            }
                            $path = Mage::getBaseDir('media') . DS . 'service' . DS . 'service' . DS;
                            $uploader = new Varien_File_Uploader('image');
                            $uploader->setAllowedExtensions(array('jpg', 'png', 'gif'));
                            $uploader->setAllowRenameFiles(true);
                            $uploader->setFilesDispersion(false);
                            $destFile = $path . $_FILES['image']['name'];
                            $filename = $uploader->getNewFileName($destFile);
                            $uploader->save($path, $filename);

                            $post_data['image'] = 'service/service/' . $filename;
                        }
                    }
                }
            } catch (Exception $e) {
                Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addError($e->getMessage());
                $this->_redirect('*/*/edit', array('id' => $this->getRequest()->getParam('id')));
                return;
            }
        //save image
        // Icon Image Save
        try {
                if ((bool) $post_data['iconimage']['delete'] == 1) {
                    $post_data['iconimage'] = '';
                } else {
                    unset($post_data['iconimage']);
                    if (isset($_FILES)) {
                        if ($_FILES['iconimage']['name']) {
                            if ($this->getRequest()->getParam("id")) {
                                $model = Mage::getModel("service/service")->load($this->getRequest()->getParam("id"));
                                if ($model->getData('iconimage')) {
                                    $io = new Varien_Io_File();
                                    $io->rm(Mage::getBaseDir('media') . DS . implode(DS, explode('/', $model->getData('iconimage'))));
                                }
                            }
                            $path = Mage::getBaseDir('media') . DS . 'service' . DS . 'service' . DS;
                            $uploader = new Varien_File_Uploader('iconimage');
                            $uploader->setAllowedExtensions(array('jpg', 'png', 'gif'));
                            $uploader->setAllowRenameFiles(true);
                            $uploader->setFilesDispersion(false);
                            $destFile = $path . $_FILES['iconimage']['name'];
                            $filename = $uploader->getNewFileName($destFile);
                            $uploader->save($path, $filename);

                            $post_data['iconimage'] = 'service/service/' . $filename;
                        }
                    }
                }
            } catch (Exception $e) {
                Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addError($e->getMessage());
                $this->_redirect('*/*/edit', array('id' => $this->getRequest()->getParam('id')));
                return;
            }

            $model = Mage::getModel("service/service")
                    ->addData($post_data)
                    ->setId($this->getRequest()->getParam("id"))
                    ->save();

            Mage::getSingleton("adminhtml/session")->addSuccess(Mage::helper("adminhtml")->__("Service was successfully saved"));
            Mage::getSingleton("adminhtml/session")->setServiceData(false);

            if ($this->getRequest()->getParam("back")) {
                $this->_redirect("*/*/edit", array("id" => $model->getId()));
                return;
            }
            $this->_redirect("*/*/");
            return;
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            Mage::getSingleton("adminhtml/session")->addError($e->getMessage());
            Mage::getSingleton("adminhtml/session")->setServiceData($this->getRequest()->getPost());
            $this->_redirect("*/*/edit", array("id" => $this->getRequest()->getParam("id")));
            return;
        }
    }
    $this->_redirect("*/*/");
}
```

Comment: Why it does not work ? If I add text or any other than file or image field type it works and in post there is everything except images or files :( HELP

Comment: @RobD.A. It is due to PHP global variables. $_POST handles all input data while $_FILES handles files data.

Comment: Yes, i know that. Last night i finally managed to make it work so now each field is sending and then controller is saving data in table. Funny thing is i tried all those things before and then it just started to work so it seems i was missing some thing. Will analyse it today again then will post final solution